# How can I add the results from SoapUI to Jira?

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, jira, soapui

I am automating some test cases in SoapUI and I have to add the results of the automated tests in Jira. How can I do that?
There will be a test case created in Jira, and I need to map that particular test case with the one I automated in SoapUI and add the results after the test has been executed.I just need to see the results Pass/Failed in the Jira test case.
Thanks

Comment: Alina, would you mind adding more details on how you want update the result in jira i.e., what format you want? Sample response would help.

Comment: Well I'm not really sure, that's why my question is so vague.I need ideas on how to do it.

Comment: I believe there is REST API provided by JIRA. However, if you have to do it manually how would you do it? Also, Is it single jira issue for single test case? Specify otherwise.

Comment: I know for a fact that the Jira has it;s own Rest API. I'm gonna do some more research and then come back with a better question.

Comment: See here for examples - https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-query-issues

Comment: There will be a test case created in Jira, and i need to map that test case with the one i automated in SoapUi and add the results after the test has been executed.No issues will be involved i just need to see the results Pass/Failed in the Jira test case.

Comment: Ok. If I got you right, you may need to add the comment in jira once the test is passed in soapui.

Comment: Passed or failed depending, and all the results I get for failed assertions for example, should be added in Jira, too.

Comment: Do you also need to close the jira issue if the test case is passed apart from adding the comment?

Comment: So i just need the results of the automated tests in Jira. No issues will be involved in this flow, only test cases.

Comment: Alina, you can check the below approach mentioned in the solution and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the approaches I would think of in this case.

Let us assume that there is a test suite in a `soapui project`.

`Jira Issue Id` should be added to the each of the test case as a custom property, say `JIRA_ID`.

The test case results can be accessed using the below `TearDown Script` of the test suite. [Below script](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html#8-Logging-results) just logs the details.

```
for ( testCaseResult in runner.results )
{
   testCaseName = testCaseResult.getTestCase().name
   log.info testCaseName
   if ( testCaseResult.getStatus().toString() == 'FAILED' )
   {
      log.info "$testCaseName has failed"
      for ( testStepResult in testCaseResult.getResults() )
      {
         testStepResult.messages.each() { msg -> log.info msg }
      }
   }
}
```

However, in your case, a comment should be added to the `jira issue id` for each test case respectively.
In order to achieve that there isn't a simple way. Use either of the below way:

1. write some code(in your preferred language) to call [JIRA REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-add-comment) to add a comment to the issue. [wslite](https://github.com/jwagenleitner/groovy-wslite#rest) is very good simple library that I would prefer.
2. Using soapui test case:

   - add a rest method to be able to comment in jira to the project. or in a separate project altogether since it not related to actual tests. see [here](https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html#15-Run-a-TestCase-located-in-another-project)
   - create a dummy test case, and add a test step using this method. this test case can in the same test suite or somewhere else in the project.
   - `do not forget` to **disable** this test case as this not your actual functional test case.
   - just update the message & run this disabled test step to update in `jira`

Below is the slightly modified test suite `TearDown Script` to accommodate your requirement. However, you need to implement `callJiraRestAPI` method using one of the above mentioned way.

```
for ( testCaseResult in runner.results ) {
   testCaseName = testCaseResult.getTestCase().name
   def jiraId = testCaseResult.getTestCase().getPropertyValue('JIRA_ID')
   log.info testCaseName
   def message = new StringBuffer()
   if ( testCaseResult.getStatus().toString() == 'FAILED' ) {
      log.info "$testCaseName has failed"
      message.append("$testCaseName has failed")
      for ( testStepResult in testCaseResult.getResults() ) {
         testStepResult.messages.each() { msg -> 
            log.info msg
            message.append(msg) 
         }
      }
   } else {
     log.info "$testCaseName has passed"
     message.append("$testCaseName has passed")
   }
   //calling jira rest api to add the comment
   callJiraRestAPI(jiraId, testCaseResult.getTestCase(), message.toString())
}


//You need to Implement calling jira rest api to add the comment
def callJiraRestAPI(jiraId, testKase, message) {
//write your code using either 1 or 2 way
//of course, REST request needs to be set with message
//and jiraId is needed and testKase is useful if you choose to use 2nd way, otherwise not needed.
}
```